# triggering actuator refresh http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh using Schedular task

Tags: spring-boot

I need to create a scheduler which will automatically hit http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh endpoint on every 3000ms. I am using cloud config to fetch data from git repositories .So i need to create a scheduler which will trigger actuator/refresh so i can fetch run time data without building and running the application. please help.